# Flutter - Version Solving Failed

Tags: flutter, dart

The error message:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 3.0.2.

Because task_timer depends on dependencies any which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
```

My pubspec.yaml:

[image]

Changed the location of my dependencies, getting less errors now
[image]

Comment: What is `task_timer`?  I don't see that listed in your dependencies, and there is no such package on pub.dev.  Is that the name of your project?  If so, are you sure that this is the `pubspec.yaml` file in the root of the `task_timer` project?

Comment: Seems like you are trying to use a task_timer package and you gave it a version of any: , you can change the version to 2.12.0  and above, this should help

Comment: @jamesdlin yes that is the name of the app and it's in the root folder

Comment: @LeenaMarie By "root folder" you mean the root of your project?  Or the root of your file system?  Is it in the same directory that you're running `flutter pub get` from?  Are you sure that this is your exact `pubspec.yaml` file? (It doesn't include the `task_timer` name, which seems suspicious, and the `dependencies` entry *within* `dev_dependencies` looks wrong.)

Comment: @jamesdlin I updated my question with a couple images, thanks for pointing out I had the dependencies in the wrong spot